# css not loaded correctly when using lazy load in create react app

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to trim the chunk size of my add using lazy loading, but I have recently landed into an issue.

One of the component uses another library Data-grid , the css for this library is not getting adding when i lazy load the component , but when use without lazy load works fine.

```
const Results = lazy(() => import("../component/result/result"));
```

does any one have suggestions why this might be happening.